# Selenium webdriver - Could not convert 'text' to string

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

First off...I am new to selenium.
I have installed selenium web driver 3.4. Node.JS, v8.2.0. Also the latest gecko driver.

I set my environment variables.

I am writing my tests in visual studio community edition.

I write the below code and when I execute it I get the below error for Firefox. I can see this was an issue but should not be an issue on the latest versions I have? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZTTH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with version 3.4 was reported here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/683. Instead of getting a string, property 'text' is being set as an array of characters.

In file *selenium/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js*, `setParameter('text', keys).` should be `setParameter('text', keys.then(keys => keys.join(''))).`

As suggested by user Skratchdot in that post, you can try editing your local install to see if things start working.

Comment: Brilliant :) Editing my local file as suggested worked. Thank you